# Position a div below responsive divs which have fixed ratios

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, position, padding

Edited for clarity:

I have a number of divs. Their width and height is responsive to the size of the browser window. `padding-top: 20%` :after a wrapper div ensures that their ratio stays the same, whatever the window shape.

I want to have a separate `div` after these, at the foot of the page - its height determined only by the text it contains. I'm struggling to position this at the foot of the page: it appears underneath the first row of divs (see the fiddle below).

https://jsfiddle.net/toLwb52h/

Thanks very much for any help!

CSS:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}

.wrapper:after {
padding-top: 20%;
display: block;
content: '';
}

.main {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
}

.ratio {
display: inline-flex;
float: left;
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
}

.red {
background-color: red;
}

.yel {
background-color: yellow;
}

.foot {
position: relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="main">
<div class="ratio yel"></div>
<div class="ratio red"></div>
<div class="ratio red"></div>
<div class="ratio yel"></div>
<div class="ratio yel"></div>
<div class="ratio red"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="foot">
<p>Text for the foot of the page </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to make it more simple, remember when you're using float don't forgot to add clear class after them

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.wrapper, .main {
    width: 100%;
}
.ratio {
    width: 50%;
    height: 600px; /* Should be flexible according to content */
    float: left;
}
.red {
    background-color: #F00;
}
.yellow {
    background-color: #FF0;
}
.clr {
    clear: both;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="ratio red"></div>
    <div class="ratio yellow"></div>
    <div class="ratio yellow"></div>
    <div class="ratio red"></div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="foot">
    <p>Text for the foot of the page </p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Kashif - that's cleaner in many ways, but losing the `padding` from `.wrapper:after` means the divs are no longer a fixed ratio. I'd like the `foot` div to be flexible according to content; the others to remain at a fixed ratio. Can you suggest anything? (Here's your code: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lc29wk6q/)).

Comment: did not understand what you want? can you please explain in more simple way so I can help

Comment: Thanks! In the original version (https://jsfiddle.net/17nt38sm/) the coloured divs maintain their ratio. This means that if your resize the _width_ of your window, their _height_ will change so that their shape remains the same. I'm looking for a way to keep that and to have another type of div (the .foot div) underneath. I'm not sure how to position this so that it's always at the bottom. Adding `padding-top: 71%;` works for the link above, but if I add more coloured divs (https://jsfiddle.net/17nt38sm/2/) I'd have to manually change that to `padding-top: 142%;`. Is there another way?